# Using trigger('click') with jQuery cross domain

Tags: jquery, html, triggers, click

I am attempting to basically launch a game from a separate site using jQuery.

http://webstudios.webs.com/rbxlaunch.htm

My source is

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ROBLOX Games!</title>
        <iframe width="100%" height="100%" id="Frame" seamless src="" scrolling=no style="position: absolute; top: 200px; left: 0px;"></iframe>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function VisitPlace(ID) {
                alert("Clicked.");
                $('#test').trigger('click');
                document.getElementById("Frame").src = "http://www.roblox.com/--place?id=" + ID;
                $("#Frame").load(function(){
                    alert("Done loading.");
                    $('#Frame').contents().find("#ctl00_cphRoblox_VisitButtons_MultiplayerVisitButton").trigger('click')
                                        alert("Enjoy the game");
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <button onclick="javascript:VisitPlace(487316);">ROBLOX remote visit test.</button>
            <button id="test" onclick="javascript:alert('Hello');">Ignore me.</button>
        </center>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm guessing it's not working due to cross domain. What work arounds are there?

Comment: is this in IE ? .. seems working in Chrome / Safari

Comment: Seems to be working for me in Opera/Chrome/IE7.

Comment: Although is working Chrome/Safari - you will get a JS error in the console

Comment: What do you mean by it's working? Getting the alerts doesn't prove anything...

Comment: the page loads .. browser does not denies the iframe load ...

Comment: @user1428716 ok, but the question is about the click, not the load

Comment: okay the page loads means - The click on the page triggers iframe load .. I am talking about iframe load .. and you would get : Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL

Comment: @user1428716 right, the question is about the js click, not the manual click, and you are getting a security error as expected.

Comment: @Christophe . thanks .. now i read the Q properly .:)

Comment: Can you please try the -  trigger click -  on your Source HTML of  http://www.roblox.com : using document.ready to trigger it

Answer (score 0):

Without human intervention, server side action or cooperation from the target site, as far as I know there's nothing you can do.

Comment: I am trying to evaluate something similar with both domains in my control. So what if we do have control over the target site?

Comment: @skaneria then the code sample in the question should work for you: $('#Frame').contents()...